# How to refer to MOOC on an academic CV?

Tags: cv, self-promotion, promotion

Quick question for the collective.

1. Is it appropriate to list completion of online courses (eg. Coursera) on your academic CV? I'm in medicine, but want to articulate that I am expanding my skill set by completing work in data science and analytics.
2. If so, where would you put it in context of your other CV sub-headings?

Comment: You do not generally put coursework (online or offline) on your CV, unless it results in a certification in which case you might list the certification.

Comment: @JeffE: I agree that the big picture of the question is a duplicate. But looking in to the details, *"I'm in medicine, but want to articulate that I am expanding my skill set by completing work in data science and analytics."*, the accepted answer of the post you've specified doesn't address the OP's concern.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based purely on my own experience -

1. I applied for a job a few months ago, and had recently completed a MOOC relating to an aspect of the project that I did not need to be qualified for, but demonstrated I had an interest in that area.  Rather than add it to my CV, I mentioned it in the covering letter.
2. Personally, I wouldn't want to clutter the academic CV too much or detract from my main qualifications - I wouldn't put it under the Academic Qualifications section for instance. However, I sometimes include a section at the end of the CV entitled 'Workshops and Classes Attended' which I tailor to include things that are relevant to a particular role, so I might put a MOOC there if it related to a position I was applying for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate to list completion of online courses (eg. Coursera) on your academic CV?

In *your* case, **yes**. Since your mainstream subjects connected to medicine differ widely from what you intend to showcase, i.e., data science and analytics, it would be advisable to add such subjects to your academic CV. Fields like genomics and bioinformatics look for candidates having skill sets in both medicine and data science. But this is applicable provided that you are *certified* in those subjects. It wouldn't be much of use otherwise.

There are some MOOCs people might attend out of interest, and even get certified, but does not create an impact in the CV, such courses are to be avoided in an academic CV to prevent losing focus of the actual achievements that connect to their objective.

> Where would you put it in context of your other CV sub-headings?

This is a matter of preference as CVs can vary widely depending on people, culture and the jobs you target. I would put it under a section named *Auxiliary Certifications* section. I did find this practice indeed useful in my career.